# How to set not open editText when click on in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I want when click on `Edittext` show my dialog. but in my codes when click on `EditText`, first select `editText` and show **keyboard** so click second click on `editText` then show my **Dialog**!

I want when click on `editText` not select `edittext` and not show keyboard just show **dialog**!

**My xml code:**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/registerCountryInptLay"
        style="@style/registerIptLytStyle"
        app:hintAnimationEnabled="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/registerCountryEdtTxt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/loginCountry"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding10" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I write below code for `editText` click event :

```
@OnClick({R.id.registerCountryEdtTxt, R.id.registerCountryInptLay})
void selectCountry() {

    final CountryPicker picker = CountryPicker.newInstance("Select Country");  // dialog title
    picker.setListener(new CountryPickerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectCountry(String name, String code, String dialCode, int flagDrawableResID) {
            // Implement your code here
            countryName = name;
            if (!countryName.isEmpty() && countryName != null) {
                countryList.setText(countryName);
            }
            picker.dismiss();
        }
    });
    picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "COUNTRY_PICKER");
}
```

how can I it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add below properties in EditText:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="true"
```

So your code would look as below:

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/registerCountryEdtTxt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/loginCountry"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding10" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this in you OnClick method

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, but not initialize this code : `view.getWindowToken()` . I want use this code in activity.

Comment: This is to force hide soft keyboard inside activity. for view (View view = getCurrentFocus();)

Answer (score 0):

Check this code.. I think Your are using ButterKnife.

```
 registerCountryEdtTxt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerCountryEdtTxt);


    registerCountryEdtTxt.setClickable(true);
    registerCountryEdtTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            void selectCountry()
        }
    });


    void selectCountry() {

        final CountryPicker picker = CountryPicker.newInstance("Select Country");  // dialog title
        picker.setListener(new CountryPickerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectCountry(String name, String code, String dialCode, int flagDrawableResID) {
                // Implement your code here
                countryName = name;
                if (!countryName.isEmpty() && countryName != null) {
                    countryList.setText(countryName);
                }
                picker.dismiss();
            }
        });
        picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "COUNTRY_PICKER");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you Use butter Knife means check this one

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/registerCountryInptLay"
        style="@style/registerIptLytStyle"
        app:hintAnimationEnabled="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/registerCountryEdtTxt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/loginCountry"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding10" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```